# No possibility to add event listener on element what is existing

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopware

Works with Shopware 6. Currently I have a problem with adding any event in the menu for mobile devices (after clicking on the 'hamburger' icon). The menu is a slide-out, search engine, header and Menu list.

There is no problem with supporting other events in this area (except for  lists). Even a header that is also nested in the same  works for e.g. 'click' event, but no events are applied to the list any more.

Interestingly, by using the .ready function, the entire list and individual elements of that list react. Only events like 'hover', 'click' or 'mouseover' do not work.

I tried with pure javascript and jQuery.

I have structure like this:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div> 
      Text 
      <div> 
      <ul> 
         <li></li> 
         <li></li> 
         <li></li> 
      </ul> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

As I wrote, navigation is built into Shopware. The navigation works by itself, you can click on the list items. This indicates that items on this list already have other event listeners. Perhaps this has an influence on the fact that I can't sign my event listener? If so, how can I get around? No, 'pointer-events: none' is not set.

Comment: You will need to share your code so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Do you have `pointer-events: none;` set with CSS?

Comment: I have structure like this:

<div>
    <div >
        <div >
            Text 
        <div>
    <ul >
        <li > </li> 
        <li > </li> 
        <li > </li> 
    </ul>
    </div>  
</div> 

As I wrote, navigation is built into Shopware. The navigation works by itself, you can click on the list items. This indicates that items on this list already have other event listeners. Perhaps this has an influence on the fact that I can't sign my event listener?
If so, how can I get around?

No, 'pointer-events: none' is not set.